# There are total of $16$ people. How many ways can you make two committees of $8$ people in each committee?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

You have $16$ people in a class. How many ways can you make two committees of $8$ people in each committee?

How do I do this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the first committee $\binom{16}{8}$ ways.

Choose the second committee $\binom{8}{8}$ ways.

At first it looks like the total number of committees should be $\binom{16}{8}\binom{8}{8}=\binom{16}{8}\cdot 1=\binom{16}{8}$, but we have overcomunted by a factor of $2$ because we count a pair of committees twice, once when we select a committee of $8$ and once when we select its complement. So we multiply by $1/2$ to fix this over counting to get
$$
\frac{1}{2}\binom{16}{8}
$$
as the total number of pairs of committees.

Comment: You are counting each committee twice, once when you select a given committee and once when you choose its complement.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

How many ways are there to choose the first person on your committee? 16. How about the second person? 15, because there is one person who is not available. So we have $16*15*14*13*12*11*10*9$ ways. But we've overcounted because we've chosen the same committees of people in several different orders. How many times did we count each committee? This is $8!=8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1$ because there are this many ways to order $8$ people. (8 ways to choose the first, 7 ways to choose the second...) So we divide $16*15*14*13*12*11*10*9$ by $8!=8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1$ to account for the overcounting. **Assuming that we don't care to which committee a certain group of $8$ people is assigned, we must also divide by 2 because it's the same to choose a group of people or its complement.**

The final answer is $\frac{16*15*14*13*12*11*10*9}{8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1}= \frac{16!}{2*8!8!}=\frac{1}{2}\binom{16}{8}$.

Comment: You are counting each committee twice, once when you select a given committee and once when you choose its complement.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, I edited to account for this.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Amanda is one of the people in the class.  The two committees are completely determined by choosing which seven of the other fifteen people in the class will serve on the same committee as Amanda.  Hence, there are $$\binom{15}{7}$$ ways to select two committees of eight people from a class of sixteen people.

Alternatively, choose eight of the sixteen people to serve on a committee. The other eight people then form the other committee.  However, we have chosen each committee twice, once when we select a particular set of eight people and once when we choose its complement.  Hence, there are 
$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{16}{8} = \binom{15}{7}$$
ways to select two committees of eight people from a class of sixteen people.

Comment: You may count only half. (Reduce to 4 people - 2 teams. There must be 6 = $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.)

Comment: @AnaUspekova In the example you cited, there are only three ways.  Let's use Amanda, Brendan, Chloe, and David.  Either Amanda is teamed with Brendan (in which case Chloe and David form the other team), Chloe (in which case Brendan and David form the other team), or with David (in which case Brendan and Chloe form the other team).  To obtain six teams in this case, you would have to designate a different purpose for each committee, say a fundraising committee and a planning committee, so that it would matter whether Amanda was assigned to the fundraising committee or the planning committee.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative way of thinking about this problem is that you line 16 people up in a line where each position decides what committee they will be placed on. Then we must divide out the redundant combinations. so $ \frac{16!}{8!*8!} $

Comment: You are counting each committee twice, once when you select a given committee and once when you choose its complement.